# Strip 3 numeric values from string - excel

Tags: google-sheets

Ive got the below string in a Google drive spreadsheet in cell D1, what im trying to do is strip out the low the high and the average into cells F1,G1,H1

> Currently, we can provide valuations on 3, across a range of prices:
>   from  £4,694,700 to £8,091,700 - Average price £6,624,100

At the moment im using `=RIGHT(D1, 11)` in cell `H1` to get the average `£6,624,100` number, but im not sure of the best way to get the others, or how to deal with hundreds of thousands, or tens of millions

Is there a more versatile way this could be done ?

Ive made a dummy spreadsheet here : 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r_RbMjI-7KLNt8QMyQzn0d-AN1CsOxbVfjYXyoIXXFU/edit?usp=sharing

---

Ive marked this as an excel question as ive found 99% of the functions that you can use in Excel you can use in Google Spreadsheets (Google spreadsheets cant use excel macros though..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple parenthesis to extract separate capture groups, and google sheets automatically splits them into separate cells.

try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(D1,"(£.*) to (£.*) - Average price (£.*)")
```

Comment: big time ive moved the accepeted answer

Answer (score 4):

Sot the three formulas

1st number

```
=mid(D1,FIND("£",D1,1),find(" ",D1,FIND("£",D1,1))-FIND("£",D1,1))
```

2nd number

```
=mid(D1,FIND("£",D1,FIND("£",D1,1)+2),find(" ",D1,FIND("£",D1,FIND("£",D1,1)+2)+2)-FIND("£",D1,FIND("£",D1,1)+2))
```

3rd Number

```
=mid(D1,FIND("£",D1,FIND("£",D1,FIND("£",D1,1)+2)+2),999)
```

Comment: Agree that this is likely the best method, assuming that each amount is always preceded by a pound sign and that no other pound signs are present.

Comment: Thanks ! - Ive added your formulas into the google spreadsheet and locked it as view only

Comment: Note that an alternate version of finding each letter would be to use FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(D1,"$","}}}",x)), where x equals the number you're looking for. With 3 searches in this method, I think I still prefer Scott's, but if you had multiple #'s, it would be simpler to use the SUBSTITUTE method.

Comment: Also see my alternative solution using REGEXEXTRACT.

Comment: @sam give my formula a shot, does this simplify it at all?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, in cell E2, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexextract(D2:D4, {"£([0-9,]*)\s", "to £([0-9,]*)\s", "£([0-9,]*)$"} )+0)
```

and format columns E:G as valuta.

You may want to try this on a duplicate sheet because since this is an arrayformula no values or other formulas should be present in E2:G

Comment: Google Spreadsheets has a `REGEX` function that we have been pestering MSFT to introduce for many years? Remarkable.